# Replacing SQL UNION with JOINs

Tags: sql

I am pretty new to SQL and I have a question regarding joins.

I have the following three tables, where the third table can contain information on header and item level

TABLE 1 - HEADER

```
GUID

AAA
BBB
CCC
```

TABLE 2 - ITEM

```
GUID ITEMNR -> Can be 01, 02, ... 99

BBB  01
BBB  02
CCC  01
```

TABLE 3 - ADDINFO

```
GUID INFO ITEMNR -> If 00 info belongs to header, if > 00 info on item level

AAA  xx   00
BBB  yy   00
BBB  xx   10
CCC  zz   00
```

Now I want to search for guids where info = xx, but I need to find guids where info = xx (on header level) as well as the guids where at least one of the items has info = xx

So result should look like this

```
GUID ITEMNR
AAA  00
BBB  10
```

Something like the following could work but it uses UNION:

```
SELECT H.GUID, I.itemnr
from HEADER as H 
inner join ADDINFO as A on H.guid = A.guid and A.itemnr = '00'
left outer join ITEM as I on I.guid = A.guid 
where 
A.info = 'xx' and
NOT EXIST (SELECT GUID FROM ADDINFO WHERE ADDINFO.guid = I.guid and
ADDINFO.itemnr =     I.itemnr)
UNION
SELECT H2.GUID, I2.itemnr
from HEADER as H2
inner join ADDINFO as A2 on H2.guid = A2.guid and A2.itemnr > '00'
inner join ITEM as I2 on H2.guid = I2.guid 
where A.info = 'xx'
```

Does anyone of the SQL gurus knows a possibility to get the above result using only one select and joins but not 'union' and 'not exists' - In the application I am working I can not use UNION or 'NOT EXISTS'.

Comment: `UNION` and `JOIN` do very different things. You can't simply replace them.

Comment: Please explain _why_ "the application I am working I can not use UNION or 'NOT EXISTS'". This is highly unusual and needs explaining.

Comment: Do you need the guid of the header even if the match is on item level?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find groups of things with particular characeristics.  I think the best way is with a group by and having clause:

```
select guid
from addinfo
group by guid
having sum(case when info = 'xx' and itemnr = '00' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or -- items on header level
       sum(case when info = 'xx' and itemnr > '00' then 1 else 0 end) > 0    -- items on the item level
```

This encapsulates your two conditions.  It can also be simplified as:

```
select guid
from addinfo
group by guid
having sum(case when info = 'xx' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```